# How to paste in the beginning of text in a rich text box or at the end?

Tags: c#, wpf, paste

I have 2 radio buttons, both paste, but one is paste beginning and the other is paste end. Basically what needs to happen is when paste beginning is selected, the copied/cut text is pasted in the beginning of any text found in the rich text box. On the contrary, when paste end is selected, the copied/cut text needs to be automatically pasted at the end of the text in a rich text box. This is my code: (it just normal paste for now)

```
    if (rdbPasteBeginning.Checked)
        {
            if (rtbMain.SelectionLength > 0)
            {
                rtbMain.SelectionStart = rtbMain.SelectionStart + rtbMain.SelectionLength;
            }
            rtbMain.Paste();
        }
```

This is the rich text box:
http://prntscr.com/ar173t

Answer (score 0):

If you are working just with text there is no need for paste method.

You can obtain same result with simple code

```
string copiedCutText = YourMethod();
if (rdbPasteBeginning.Checked)
{
   rtbMain.Text = copiedCutText + rtbMain.Text;
}
else
{
rtbMain.Text += copiedCutText;
}
```

If you need help with new lines, or spaces, leave a comment

Comment: I'm a beginner ... what do you mean by "YourMethod" ?

Comment: string copiedCutText = YourMethod(); this represents the text you want to add at the beginning/end. string copiedCutText(you can of course change the name) is equal to YourMethod(). Instead of method you can use textBox1.text. Anyway this string will hold the text you want to add

Comment: Basically I don't know what you want to add because you Paste() method was empty